# How to add subtitles to video using ffmpeg without losing video thumbnail?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am trying to add subtitles to a video with ffmpeg. The video has a thumbnail. Whenever I try to add subtitles to video the thumbnail gets removed.
Ok, so here's what I did before running in this problem.
I've used ffmpeg to add thumbnail to video by:
`ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i image.png -map 0 -map 1 -c copy -c:v:1 png -disposition:v:1 attached_pic out-tt.mp4`
Then I used this command for adding subtitle:
`ffmpeg -i out-tt.mp4 -i subt.srt -c copy -c:s mov_text out-ss.mp4`
when I checked my file in File explorer video thumbnail was gone.
I am including ffprobe output of video file before and after adding subtitles:
**Before adding subtitles(and after adding thumbnail)out-tt.mp4**

```
D:\Videos>ffprobe out-tt.mp4
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000002763326e700] stream 0, timescale not set
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'out-tt.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.47.100
  Duration: 00:07:04.42, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 803 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 665 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
    Stream #0:2: Video: png, rgb24(pc), 1280x720, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc (attached pic)
```

**After adding subtitles (out-ss.mp4)**

```
D:\Videos>ffprobe out-ss.mp4
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'out-ss.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.47.100
  Duration: 00:07:04.91, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 801 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 665 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
    Stream #0:2(und): Subtitle: mov_text (tx3g / 0x67337874), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
```

Does anybody have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: add `-map 0 -map 1` to second cmdline